# Pip not installing packages to my Python virtual environment

Tags: python3, pip

I setup my virtual environment using the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 /opt/virtualenvironment/project_1
cd /opt/virtualenvironment/project_1/bin
source activate
```

I then ran:

```
pip3 install anypackage
python3
import anypackage
```

Gives not found. However when I deactivate my environment and go into python3, I can import that package.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `import json_flatten` instead of `import json-flatten` in the last line? `import json-flatten` would give `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: yep any package example will do

Comment: When in the venv, what does `which pip3` return? Did you explicitly install pip in the venv?

Comment: this returns /usr/local/bin/pip3